# How to use term-aggregations in elastic search for OR-options

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation, facet

Suppose I have the following data:

```
car1: { color: blue, brand: mercedes }
car2: { color: blue, brand: toyota }
car3  { color: red,  brand: mercedes }
car4: { color: red,  brand: toyota }
car5: { color: green,brand: toyota }
```

An aggregation for "color" gives me `{ blue: 2, red: 2, green: 1}`

An aggregation for "brand" gives me `{ mercedes: 2, toyota: 3 }`

Fine so far.

If I search for "color = blue" and do my aggregations AFTER filtering i end up with:

Aggregation "color" gives me `{ blue: 2 }` // only for blue cars

Aggregation "brand" gives me `{ mercedes: 1, toyota: 1 }` // only for blue cars

In my search, I may chose more than one aspect for each Attribute, so a search for "blue" or "red" or "green" cars would give me all records.

So I would like to get each aggregation value BEFORE filtering the corresponding attribute, but AFTER other attributes, so I can see the other amounts as well.

Using post-filters is not applicable here (circular reference).

Do I really have to fire multiple queries (for main query and each aggregation)?

Or do I have to use all aggregation before post-filtering and put all filters except the corresponding again in each aggregation (filter-aggr.)?

Any help appreciated!

---

[A]
No filters

```
Color:
  ( ) blue: 2
  ( ) red: 2
  ( ) green: 1
Brand:
  ( ) toyota: 3
  ( ) mercedes: 2
```

[B]
Filter: color=blue

```
Color:
  (x) blue: 2
Brand:
  ( ) toyota: 1
  ( ) mercedes: 1
```

[C]
Filter: color=blue

```
Color:
  (x) blue: 2
  ( ) red: 2
  ( ) green: 1
Brand:
  ( ) toyota: 1
  ( ) mercedes: 1
```

Comment: Is your goal to keep your aggregations or facets global, regardless of what the user searches for (Example C above)? Or to have your aggregations filtered by the facets that the user selects (Example B above)?

Comment: Not exactly global .. Filtering generally should influence facet-values. But filtering should NOT influence the facet for each filtered attribute itself. Filtering for color should influence brand values, but not color values - et vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which of the above example functionality you want, here are some queries that will get you there.

For Example B:
This query will give you aggregations across the query only. The first time it is run on page load, there would be no terms in the query section so you would get a full aggregate list for colors and brands. If the user selected the blue facet, then the query will only return documents matching that facet. This would mean the aggregations generated from that returned set would match the facet lists you have in Example B.

```
POST /cars/car/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "color": {
              "value": "blue"
           }
        }
    }, 
    "aggs" : {
        "colors" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "color" }
        },
        "brands" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "brand" } 
        }
    }
}
```

Example C:
For Example C, I believe your goal is that all potential facets should be visible, even after a search has been executed. To do this, you want to create an aggregate that uses the global context to get all documents, not just the ones returned by the query. In this example, all searches will return the full list of facets for both color and brand.

```
POST /cars/car/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "color": {
              "value": "blue"
           }
        }
    }, 
    "aggs" : {
        "all_cars" : {
            "global": {},
            "aggs" : {
                "colors" : {
                    "terms" : { "field" : "color" }
                },
                "brands" : {
                    "terms" : { "field" : "brand" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your goal is to allow the user to always see all available facets, then make sure your query adjusts itself based on the number and type of facets the user has selected.

UPDATE: Per comment below, this will combine both options. You can get both full unfiltered aggregates and the filtered aggregates this way. You would have to programmatically decide which facet list to use in your display based on the user's actions.

```
POST /cars/car/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "color": {
              "value": "blue"
           }
        }
    }, 
    "aggs" : {
        "colors" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "color" }
        },
        "brands" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "brand" } 
        },
        "all_cars" : {
                "global": {},
                "aggs" : {
                    "colors" : {
                        "terms" : { "field" : "color" }
                    },
                    "brands" : {
                        "terms" : { "field" : "brand" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update 2: You can also nest aggregations so that you can pre-calculate the various facets by filters.

```
POST /cars/car/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "colors" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "color" },
            "aggs" : {
                "brandsByColor" : {
                    "terms" : { "field" : "brand" }
                }
            }
        },
        "brands" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "brand" },
            "aggs" : {
                "colorsByBrand" : {
                    "terms" : { "field" : "color" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not exactly, filterings for brand should influence the facet-values for color and vice versa ... you see?

Comment: So if I understand, you want to have facet selections effect other facet lists. So if the client selects "blue" in colors, it should filter brands, but the colors facet list should still be the full list.

Comment: Exactly .. so aggregation for brands needs results filtered for colors and aggregation for colors needs results filtered for brands .. but since you can only "query -> filter -> aggr. -> postfilter" i do not see how to achieve desired results.

Comment: Use the updated search query. It will give you access to both the full unfiltered aggregations and the filtered aggregations. Then only display the ones you need based on the user's actions.

Comment: What do you mean with "updated search query" - is this a feature of ES?

Comment: I was referring to Update 2 in my answer, which I added shortly after that comment due to size restrictions in the comments.

Comment: hey @rclement I used the updated answer and the aggregates are replicated in each returned aggregate from colours, example: Color1: 2 documents and have an inner array with all colors. Color2: 3 documents and also has all colors as an inner array. The inner array is called brandsByColor. For each aggregate result for colors, I have an inner aggregate result ... Any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it.

You need ElasticSearch 1.4 to do this, and it is achieved with filter-aggregations and "postfilters".
Prior to 1.4 I was doing this with filtered query in order to get the proper aggregation counts  and was trying to achieve this with "global: {}, filter: {}" aggregations. Like in the answer above. The problem is that the global {} aggregation ignores the query itself and if you are doing full-text search pararelly to the filtering, it will not work.

Now in 1.4. all you have to do is run the normal unfiltered query and apply postfilters to it. And for the aggregations you use filter aggregations, where you you apply all postfilters, EXCEPT FOR THE ONE THAT IS ON THE FIELD THAT THE AGGREGATION IS APPLIED TO.

So in your example you will have an AND postfilter on both colors and brands. And in the colors-aggregation you will have the brands filter, while in the brands aggregation you will have the colors-filter.

In my case I have company_id and subjects filters. Previously I would do this, but it would work only for match_all query.

```
POST /cars/car/_search
{
    "size": "20",
    "from": "0",
    "aggs": {
        "company_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "company_id",
                "size": 10
            }
        },
        "global_company": {
            "global": {},
            "aggs": {
                "company_id_3": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "subjects": "710"
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "company_id_2": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "company_id"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "company_id": "1215"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "subjects": "710"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I do this, and it works for all:

```
POST /cars/car/_search
{
    "size": "20",
    "from": "0",
    "aggs": {
        "company_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "company_id",
                "size": 10
            }
        },
        "global_company": {
            "global": {},
            "aggs": {
                "company_id_3": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "subjects": "710"
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "company_id_2": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "company_id"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
        "and": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "company_id": "1215"
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "subjects": "710"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can see how I have applied only the other filter on the company_id_3 aggregation. And here you can replace the match_all query with any query that pleases you and you will still get the OR-logic you need

Comment: I *think* this answer addresses the original question more precisely than rclement's answer (but they're both very useful and informative nonetheless).

Answer (score 0):

> Or do i have to use all aggregation before post-filtering and put all
>   filters except the corresponding again in each aggregation
>   (filter-aggr.)?

do this.